Radiation from a 2D mirrored box
I came across an elegant maths proof here1, which is related to "black body" radiation.  It's a kind of "toy thought experiment".
A unit square has perfectly mirrored sides but small apertures at each corner.  A light photon enters the box at one corner at some angle to a side of the square, travelling in the plane of the square.  For what angles will the photon eventually emerge at one of the corners, and what will the length of the path be that it traverses?  Two versions of the proof were given of which the most elegant is a graphic construction.  I have two extensions to the question which are puzzling me and others may find entertaining.

Suppose we place an isotropic monochromatic emitter at one corner that radiates uniformly over the right-angle, what proportion of the emitted light will emerge from the corners?
How does the problem generalise to a cubic mirrored box?


At the level of idealization you're asking about, this is really more of a question about abstract mathematical measure theory than a question about physics.

How is your construct related to black body radiation if you don't have anything to say about the temperature of the walls of the box?

Michael, valid point though the boundary is somewhat fuzzy I think!

Solomon, I thought the "experiment" has some relationship to the cavity models used in black body analysis to explain the (lack of) the UV catastrophe.  I was trying to find a useful tag and this is what came up!

Black body simulators like this one use a cavity with walls whose inner surface roughly approximates a true black body—very far from mirror-like—and, whose temperature is precisely controlled.

On further thought I think the answer to question 1 is, zero!  The condition on an angle for a photon to emerge at a corner is that its tangent is an irreducible rational fraction <= 1.  Since in any interval there are infinitely more irrationals than rationals, this result follows.  An interesting correspondence between what appears to be an idealised physics problem and number theory.
